# Android: Get NullPointerException When Sending Notification From Service

Tags: java, android, service, notifications

I cant send notification from my android app service, here is my error log

```
01-03 20:41:01.075: W/dalvikvm(7009): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fcd2a0)
01-03 20:26:31.795: E/AndroidRuntime(4186): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1428
01-03 20:26:31.795: E/AndroidRuntime(4186): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-03 20:26:31.795: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
01-03 20:26:31.795: E/AndroidRuntime(4186):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3615)
```

and here is my code in my service

```
int noid = 1;
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("Title")
    .setContentText("Text message");
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
        0,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(noid, mBuilder.build());
```

Please help

Thank you

Comment: show **whole** stacktrace

Comment: At which line you got NPE?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: there is nothing any other stacktrace related to the problem

Comment: @PiyushGupta at last line, mNotificationManager.notify(noid, mBuilder.build());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Context` you're passing to `Intent` constructor is `null`.

`Service` is-a `Context` so within a `Service` you can use `this` as a context.

Comment: how can I fix it? sorry I am newbie in java android

Comment: i have tried that, but always give me error. I think `this` should be used in activity, not in Service because Service is a Context.

Comment: `Activity` is-a `Context` as well.

Comment: yes, that's correct, but if I use `this`, I get error undefined or can not be resolve, error disappear if I use `context`

Comment: The code is in an anonymous subclass? Use `YourService.this` to qualify.

Comment: I use service to start a thread and keep it alive, this thread is to check update periodically and I need to send a notification, the code is in class `CheckUpdate` extends `Thread`

Comment: thanks for your answer, you said that the `Context` is null is correct, it is because a `Thread` doesn't have any direct access to `Context` by default, now it is solved, thank you